# Is there a way to find out which unit test has thrown a stack overflow exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio, test-explorer

I have a project with more than a thousand unit tests. When I run all unit tests, the execution fails with the following message on the test output:
`Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.`

Sadly, Visual Studio does not point out the unit test, which caused the exception. Is there a way to find out, where the stack overflow occured? Can I find out which unit test ran last and which one was planned to be excueted next?

Comment: In visual studio you can debug tests. The exception should be then shown in the user interface. except it is deactivated in exception settings.

Comment: What unit test framework are you using?

Comment: Even with 1000 tests you should hopefully be able to [binary chop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to isolate the test of interest.

Comment: @SebastianSiemens: Unfortunately, it seems that (at least in some cases) a StackOverflowException is not catchable in some versions of .NET and just kills the test process. I recently ran into this issue as well, but didn't have time to write a minimum repro example yet.

Comment: I guess some form of recursion is involved, and I guess there are only a few places in code where recursion is used. You can start from there.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/test-explorer-faq?view=vs-2022#test-explorer-sorting